# Classifying Simple Graphs with Rank 2 and 3

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I asked to classify simple graphs with adjacency matrices of rank $2$ or $3$. It is easy to see when the number of vertices is $2$ and $3$ that the only such graphs are $K_2$ and $K_3$. However, I do not know how to classify graphs with rank $2$ and $3$ in general.

I am studying algebraic graph theory from Algebraic Graph Theory by Biggs but haven't progressed much in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Misha Lavrov - he noticed my mistake.

Hints for the case when the rank is $2$.

1. It is sufficient to describe graphs without isolated vertices.
2. The adjacency matrix of each complete bipartite graph has rank $2$.
   If $\{v_1,\ldots,v_s\}$ and $\{v_{s+1},\ldots,v_n\}$ ($n>s\geq1$) are his parts, then the adjacency matrix of such graph has the form
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0&0&\ldots&0&1&\ldots&1\\
     0&0&\ldots&0&1&\ldots&1\\  
     \ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\
     0&0&\ldots&0&1&\ldots&1\\
     1&1&\ldots&1&0&\ldots&0\\
     \ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots &\ldots\\  
     1&1&\ldots&1&0&\ldots&0\\
   \end{pmatrix},
   $$
   where the upper block of zeros has dimensions $s\times s$.
3. Reverse. Let $G$ be a graph.
   Call the rank of graph $G$ the rank of an adjacency matrix of $G$.
   If $G$ has no isolated vertices and is not connected, then $\operatorname{rank}(G)\geq4$.
4. If $uv$ and $xy$ are edges of $G$ and $u$
   is not adjacent to both $x$ and $y$, then $\operatorname{rank}(G)\geq4$.
   Let us number the vertices of graph $G$ such that $x_1=u$, $x_2=v$, $x_3=x$, $x_4=y$.
   The first four rows of an adjacency matrix of graph $G$ have the form:
   $$
   \begin{pmatrix}
     0&1&0&0&*&\ldots&*\\
     1&0&*&*&*&\ldots&*\\
     0&*&0&1&*&\ldots&*\\
     0&*&1&0&*&\ldots&*\\
   \end{pmatrix}.
   $$
   We see that the minor in the first four columns equals $1$.
5. Similarly it is proved that if graph $G$ has triangle, then the rank of $G$ is at least $3$.
6. Let $G$ be a connected graph of rank $2$ and $v\in V(G)$.
   Let $W=N_G(v)$ be neighbors of vertex $v$.
   Let $U=V(G)\setminus W$.
   It follows from 5 that $W$ is an independent set.
   It follows from 4 that $U$ is an independent set and each vertex of $U$ is connected with each vertex of $W$.
   If $|W|=m$, $|U|=n$, then $G=K_{m,n}$.

For the case when the rank is equal to 3. Compute the rank of the adjacency matrix of such a graph:

**Supplement.**

Another approach could be purely algebraic.
Briefly, it is as follows.

**I.** Let $G$ be a rank 2 graph with no isolated vertices and let $x$ and $y$ form a basis of the rows of an adjacency matrix $A$ of $G$. Let
$$
x=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n),
y=(\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_n).
$$
It is not difficult to see that

1. $\alpha_i+\beta_i =1$ for any $i$ y
2. Every row of $A$ coincides with either $x$ or $y$.
3. Hence we conclude that the vertices $x$ and $y$ are adjacent and graph $G$ is a complete bipartite graph.

**II.** The case when the rank of $G$ is $3$.
Just the basic steps:

1. If the graph $G$ is connected and the rank of $G$ is $3$, then $G$ has triangles.
2. Choose three rows $x,y,z$ that form the basis of rows of the adjacency matrix $A$ of $G$. We can assume that the vertices $x,y,z$ form a triangle. (We denote the vertices and their corresponding rows $A$ by the same symbol.)
3. Every row of $A$ coincides with either $x$ or $y$ or $z$.
4. Hence we conclude that graph $G$ is the complete tripartite graph.

**Note 1.** I'm a little confused by the term rank of a graph. The fact is that in the literature it is understood as a variety of things. Here the rank of a graph means the rank of its adjacency matrix.

**Note 2.** The given classification in the case of rank $3$ is also a bit confusing. It is possible that I am wrong.  I will try to prepare a detailed description of each step.

**Supplement 2.**

**Proof II.1.**

Suppose the graph $G$ has no triangles.

(i) If $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ is a path in $G$, then the vertices $x_1$ and $x_4$ are adjacent.

If they are not, write out the first 4 rows of the adjacency matrix $G$.
Choose the numbering of vertices of $G$ so that $x_i$ is the first.
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  0&1&0&0&*&\ldots&*\\ 
  1&0&1&0&*&\ldots&*\\
  0&1&0&1&*&\ldots&*\\
  0&0&1&0&*&\ldots&*\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We see that $\operatorname{rank}(G)\geq4$.

(ii)
The graph $G$ is bipartite.

For this it is sufficient to prove that $G$ has no cycles of odd length.
If $x_1,\ldots,x_s$ is the shortest cycle of odd length,
then $s\geq5$ and according to (i) $x_1$ and $x_4$ are adjacent.
But then the cycle $x_1,x_4,\ldots,x_s$ has length $s-2<s$.

(iii)
Let us prove that $G$ is a complete bipartite graph.

Let $U$ and $W$ be parts of graph $G$.
Let there exist two non-adjacent vertices $x\in U,y\in W$. 
Since the graph $G$ is connected, there exist paths connecting $x$ and $y$.
Choose a shortest path among them:
$x=x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,\ldots,x_r,y_r=y$ where $x_1,\ldots,x_r\in U$, $y_1,\ldots,y_r\in W$ and $r\geq2$.
If $r>2$, then by (i) $x$ and $y_2$ are adjacent and hence the path
$x=x_1,y_2,\ldots,x_r,y_r=y$
is shorter.

(iv)
As we know a complete bipartite graph has rank $2$.
This contradicts the condition that $\operatorname{rank}(G)=3$.

**Proof II.2.**

Choose the numbering of vertices of $G$ so that $x,y,z$ is the first:
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0&1&1&*&\ldots&*\\
  1&0&1&*&\ldots&*\\
  1&1&0&*&\ldots&*\\
  \alpha_1&\alpha_2&\alpha_3&*&\ldots&*\\
  \ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We see that the first three rows of $A$ are linearly independent and hence the basis of the rows of $A$.

**Proof II.3.**

Let $v=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\ldots)$ be some row of the matrix $A$.
We have
$$
v=\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z.
$$
Consider four cases:

(1) $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=0\Rightarrow \alpha=\beta=\gamma=0\Rightarrow v=0$.
This is impossible since $G$ has no isolated vertices.

(2) Among $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ exactly two numbers are $0$.
We can assume that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ and $\alpha_3=1$.
So $\alpha=1/2$, $\beta=1/2$, $\gamma=-1/2$.
This is also impossible because otherwise in the corresponding column of the matrix $A$
the first three entries are equal to $0,0,1$ and we obtain that
$\alpha\cdot0+\beta\cdot0+\gamma\cdot1=-1/2$.

(3) Among $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ there is exactly single number equal to $0$.
We can assume that $\alpha_1=0$ and $\alpha_2=\alpha_3=1$.
So $\alpha=1$, $\beta=0$, $\gamma=0$.
Hence $v=x$.

(4) $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\alpha_3=1\Rightarrow \alpha=\beta=\gamma=1/2$.
This is impossible because otherwise in the corresponding column of the matrix $A$
the first three entries are equal to $1,1,1$ and we obtain that
$\alpha\cdot1+\beta\cdot1+\gamma\cdot1=3/2$.

We see that any row of the matrix $A$ is equal to one of the rows $x,y,z$.

**Note 3.** Since the matrix $A$ is symmetric,
the same reasoning shows that there are exactly two $1$s
among the first three occurrences of each column of the matrix $A$.
In other words, each vertex of graph $G$ is adjacent to exactly two vertices of $x,y,z$.

**Proof II.4.**

Let $X$ be the set of all those vertices of graph $G$ whose corresponding rows in $A$ are equal to $x$.
Similarly, define $Y$ and $Z$.
Clearly, $X,Y,Z$ are independent sets.
Let $u\in X$, $v\in Y$.
As can be seen from the following scheme,
since $u=x$, $v=y$ and among the first three entries of columns $u$ and $v$
there should be exactly two 1s of vertices $u$ and $v$ adjacent.
$$
\begin{matrix}
    & & & u &&& v & \\
  x & & & 0 &&& 1 &\\
  y & & & 1 &&& 0 &\\
  z & & & 1 &&& 1 &\\  
  &&&&&&&\\
  u&&&0&&&1&\\  
  &&&&&&&\\
  v&&&1&&&0&\\  
\end{matrix}.
$$

Comment: The graph in your image is the complete tripartite graph $K_{1,1,n}$. Doesn't any complete tripartite graph have rank 3? And how should I proceed?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I have supplemented my answer and am ready to answer any of your questions.